# GridBagLayout works for higher resolution but not for lower

Tags: java, swing, resolution, layout-manager

I use a GridBagLayout to center the menu for my game in a jframe and it works fine on my stationary computer with a screen resolution of 1920x1080 but when I use the exact same code but on my laptop the menu never shows up.

This is the code for adding the menu to the jframe:

```
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        if(menu.checkGame() == false){
            menu.setLayout(null);
            menu.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1400, 1080));
            load.setBackground(true);
            frame.add(menu, new GridBagConstraints());
        }
```

Why doesn't it work on a lower resolution and how could I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't hardcode a preferred size. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager will determine the preferred size and center the menu accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a GridBagLayout doesn't have enough room for every child component's preferred size, it sets each component to its minimum size.  Try adding `menu.setMinimumSize(menu.getPreferredSize())`.